# Checked out xcode project from SVN, Getting build errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, svn

I'm trying to get my xcode project setup on a source control server, and after I successfully import my xcode project into the repository either using the command line import command or manually checking out the repository, adding the files, and committing (I've tried both), I always get this linker command failed with exit code 1.  I've gotten this before with bad references, and I imagine it's something related to files specific to the machine the project was created on, but I am at a loss as to what I need to do to fix this issue.  Here's a screenshot of the error:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swhbA.png)

The error message is:

```
ld: library not found for -lfreetds
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried deleting the user data folder from the project file, messing with the settings, updating subversion, removing from the repository and putting it back on over and over.  Please help!!

Comment: looks like you are missing freetds on your development machine. the error says `library not found for -lfreetds`